# Sorting associative array / javascript object by keys alphabetically

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How do i order this object by the keys, Alphabetically?

I tried:

```
racks.sort();
```

The object racks is filled like this:

(Statdev is a string, and kartnr and bitnrk are integers)

```
racks[jPunten[i].STATDEV] = {
                            label: '',
                            punkt: [{
                            x: jPunten[i].KARTNR,
                            y: jPunten[i].BITNRK}]
```

Some Firebug output (i also noticed that in firebug the object IS ordered alphabetically):

```
racks
    []

DAY
    Object { punkt=[8], label=""}

label
    ""

punkt
    [Object { x="12", y="1"}, Object { x="12", y="2"}, Object { x="12", y="3"}, 5 meer...]

0
    Object { x="12", y="1"}

1
    Object { x="12", y="2"}

2
    Object { x="12", y="3"}

3
    Object { x="12", y="4"}

4
    Object { x="12", y="5"}

5
    Object { x="12", y="6"}

6
    Object { x="12", y="7"}

7
    Object { x="12", y="8"}

LSF01
    Object { punkt=[1], label=""}

label
    ""

punkt
    [Object { x="1", y="10"}]

0
    Object { x="1", y="10"}

x
    "1"

y
    "10"
```

Comment: There is no inherent order in JavaScript objects. If you need a reliable sorting, create an array of keys and sort that.

Comment: You can't sort objects. They are sorted by key names automatically (in most cases).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript impossible to sort object properties by keys. If you need it, you can put to array all keys of object, to sort them and then work with properties in desired order.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sort = function(obj, comparator) {
    var array = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        array.push([obj[i], i]);
    }
    array.sort(function(o1, o2) {
        return comparator(o1[0], o2[0]);
    });
    var newObj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        newObj[array[i][1]] = array[i][0];
    }
    return newObj;
}
```

Comment: What is the comparator? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Do two arrays:

- one array for the keys
- the second associative array, using the key
  value pair, is actually an object.

// normal object notation

```
var personObject = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe"};
alert('personObject.firstName - ' + personObject.firstName);
```

// add to object using object-array notation, note: doing this will convert an array to an object

```
personObject["age"] = 46;
```

// array of keys, sorted

```
var keysArray = ["firstName", "lastName"];
keysArray[keysArray.length] = "age";
keysArray.sort();
```

// get object value, using array-object notation with array as key

```
alert('personObject[keysArray[0]] - ' + personObject[keysArray[0]]);
```